# In a regression, is an independent variable still useful if it is the same for each subject between observations?

Tags: regression, r, time-series, validity

I was not able to find an answer to this question, as I feel it is rather specific and awkward to ask. But, here goes. This is a simplified version of my data:

[image]

As you can see, I have various subjects and I am measuring three variables for each of them each year. Variable 1 and Variable 2 are completely variable for each subject and for each year.

Variable 3, however, is the same for each subject between years. Variable 3 has a value of 500 for Subject A in 2000, 2001, and 2002; and it has a value of 1678 for Subject B in 2000, 2001, and 2002; and so on.

I am wanting to do a regression analysis on this data, and I am wondering whether Variable 3 would still be a valid or useful independent variable to use in the regression. I want to use it if possible because I think it would be a useful control variable for my specific data, to show variation in Variables 1 and 2 between Subjects.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to include Variable 3.

You have a hierarchical dataset, with yearly observations (level-1 units) nested within individuals (level-2 units).

Within this structure, you can have explanatory variables at level 1 or level 2. Any level-2 explanatory variable (such as Variable 3) will be the same for all observations from the same level-2 unit but differ for observations in different level-2 units.

Comment: And then use a model for hiërarchical data, in line with what Doctor Milt (+1) described. E.g. lmer in R, or mixed in spss.

Answer (score 0):

The two variables you ask about (Subject and Variable 3) are completely confounded.  There is nothing to be gained by including both in a statistical analysis.  Any effect you notice for Subjects might actually be due to Variable 3, and vice versa.  (Perhaps the confounding you have in your full data set is less than complete.  In which case, the degree of confounding would logically need to be considered in designing your statistical analysis.)

Comment: The OP does not mention using Subject as an explanatory variable, only Variables 1-3. Even so, it would be perfectly sensible to include Subject as a random intercept.

Comment: But a random intercept across subject is possible with lmer or any mixed effects model.

Comment: @DoctorMilt I would hesitate to include both `Subject` as a random intercept and `Variable3` as a fixed effect. If there aren't many more subjects and a rather strong linear relationship with `Variable3`, I would expect singularity/convergence issues.

Comment: @Roland Assuming that there are enough subjects to make random intercepts worthwhile (the OP stated that this is a simplified version of the data set), I don't see the downside of including a level-2 covariate. If `Variable3` has some predictive value, not including it will just increase the variance of the random intercepts.